# How to adapt a Moving Average period to market conditions?

Tags: volatility, market, moving-average

I would like to know if there is some way to adapt the period of a moving average to market conditions like for instance the stop loss can be adapted to market conditions using the average true range. Thanks!

EDIT: As suggested, I add some references and context to my question.

I have a trend following system that in the test period 2009 - 2014, with one hour candles, no parameters to optimize, EUR/USD produces these figures:

```
Max drawdown        -48$ 13% (MAE -74$ 20%)
Number of trades    165 (28/year, 1/week, 1/day)
Percent winning     31%
Annual return       139%
Profit factor       1.99 (PRR 1.56)
Sharpe ratio        0.92
Kelly criterion     0.55
R2 coefficient      0.647
Ulcer index         9.4%
```

However the same system in 2003 - 2008 makes:

```
    Max drawdown        -131$ 158% (MAE -154$ 185%)
    Number of trades    212 (36/year, 1/week, 1/day)
    Percent winning     19%
    Annual return       14%
    Profit factor       1.15 (PRR 0.90)
    Sharpe ratio        0.27
    Kelly criterion     0.39
    R2 coefficient      0.110
    Ulcer index         68.2%
```

So I tried to look for an adaptive moving average that adapts to market conditions, I read among others these two references:

http://www.mesasoftware.com/papers/MAMA.pdf
[(just in case it goes down)](http://web.archive.org/web/20141021073610/http://www.mesasoftware.com/Papers/MAMA.pdf)
https://books.google.com.uy/books?id=_KjOT1b9bfUC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false

I have tried to reproduce the method of the first link mith mixed results, I tested with EUR/USD and candles of 8 hours this code, sorry for the length, I hope you bear with me:

```
vars Price = series(price());           
Stop = 2*ATR(100);  
MAMA(Price,0.05,0.5);
vars MAMAs = series(rMAMA);
vars FAMAs = series(rFAMA);

if( crossUnder(FAMAs,MAMAs) ){
    reverseShort(1);//if the Following Adaptive Moving Average crosses under the Mother of Adaptive Moving Averages then I enter long, closing previous short if any
} else if( crossOver(FAMAs,MAMAs) ) {
    reverseLong(1);
}
plot("price",Price[0],MAIN|LINE,BLACK);
plot("Mama",MAMAs,LINE,RED);
plot("Fama",FAMAs,LINE,BLUE);
```

Testing that in 2009 - 2014 gave

```
Max drawdown        -157$ 64% (MAE -159$ 65%)
Number of trades    392 (68/year, 2/week, 1/day)
Percent winning     62%
Annual return       35%
Profit factor       1.15 (PRR 1.00)
Sharpe ratio        0.52
Kelly criterion     0.73
R2 coefficient      0.002
Ulcer index         21.2%
```

But in 2003 - 2008 it gives

```
Max drawdown        -255$ -1396% (MAE -255$ -1397%)
Number of trades    383 (66/year, 2/week, 1/day)
Percent winning     60%
Annual return       -2%
Profit factor       0.99 (PRR 0.85)
Sharpe ratio        -0.02
Kelly criterion     -0.05
R2 coefficient      0.013
Ulcer index         38.7%
```

However if I test in 2003 - 2008 with **4 hour candles** the results are

```
Max drawdown        -145$ 67% (MAE -146$ 67%)
Number of trades    790 (134/year, 3/week, 1/day)
Percent winning     61%
Annual return       32%
Profit factor       1.10 (PRR 0.99)
Sharpe ratio        0.50
Kelly criterion     0.71
R2 coefficient      0.415
Ulcer index         23.0%
```

So, even this 'adaptive' moving average needed to be adapted to a different market by adjusting the duration of candles, but I don't know whether this is curve fitting. Is there a way to detect this change in market conditions between 2003 - 2008 and 2009 - 2014 in this test?

Comment: Adapt to do _what_?

Comment: To perform a Trend Following strategy. In backtests I noticed that with an X-day moving average an strategy is profitable (Sharpe Ratio = 1.1, Ulcer Index = 4%) in 2009-2014 but for 2002-2008 the same strategy is not longer profitable.

Should I add "for Trend Trading" to the title in order to clarify? I am open to suggestions to clarify the title.

Comment: Hi @MithPaul! I think you're asking how to print money. Anyway, I know that some models can detect the probabitlity of a being in a market state/scenario, but I honestly don't know how much that can be useful. Browse Markow Swithing regression model (Hamilton, 1994) if you are interested in

Comment: What makes you think that MAs should work anyway?

Comment: The problem is: How do you know which model to switch to before it happens? You will know if we are in a contracting volume/price only after it happened. Maybe you could calculate the probability of a contracting range after an impulsive movement?

Comment: @Quantopic : I know that its an ambitious question but I don't want to print money :) My motivation comes after reading the works of John Elhers in which he decomposes the market into two modes, trend mode and cycle mode. However, I wasn't able to reproduce the usefulness of MAMA indicator.

Comment: @vonjd : I think trend following should work because of Dow Theory, or at least a self-fullfiling prophecy (herd mentality?)

Comment: @sparkle: That's it, I have experimented with using volatility indicators (bollinger bands, ATR, Alligator) and compress them with a Fisher transform (or a Z transform, one that normalizes the data) to see when the values go out of the compressed range and use that as a 'signal' to adjust  the MA lenght but it did not work.

Comment: To illustrate the references of my research, here are some links:

https://books.google.com.uy/books?id=_KjOT1b9bfUC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false
http://www.mesasoftware.com/papers/EmpiricalModeDecomposition.pdf
http://etfhq.com/blog/2011/02/12/fractal-dimension/

Comment: Even in random time series you have more 'trends' than you would believe intuitively. Trend following works when there are these 'trends' but fails in all other market environments. See this paper: http://www.frankfurt-school.de/clicnetclm/fileDownload.do?goid=000000311260AB4

Comment: @MithPaul, so, you want to be able to detect a trend in a time-series, in practice? could you edit the question by adding the references and how would you use them in your project? IMHO, it should make the question clearer and increase the likelihood to get proper answers.

Comment: @vonjd : Many thanks for that paper, I am haven't finished it but what I have read looks like a very comprehensive study.

Comment: Thanks @Quantopic , I added some references and context to the question.

Answer (score -1):

As it was already mentioned. Try to read about Kalman filter and Markow Switching models. I have even seen some academic papers where authors tried to define MA length based on MSM or KF. Try to google it ...

Comment: The question is _how_ to adapt a MA. Now how does your answer tackle this question? I myself use HMMs in my research but I don't _modify_ MAs with the output, so I don't see the link here.

Comment: ...and answers that just say: google _something_ and 'I have seen some papers' are frowned upon in this community.